# AuthGuard service canActivate doesn't navigate when token refreshed

Tags: angular, jwt

I am having an odd issue with `AuthGuard`.

When I click a link, it checks to see is the user has a valid access token.  If not, it will look for a refresh token, then attempt to use it to obtain an access token (`this.oAuthService.refreshToken()`).

It seems to not navigate if a refresh is required.  The token is refreshed, but the page doesn't navigate.  I can then successfully navigate after clicking the link of the protected page a second time, after the token refresh has taken place.

```js
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean>
{
    this.authUserService.lastUrl = state.url;

    if (this.oAuthService.hasValidAccessToken()) {
      this.authUserService.requireLoginSubject.next(false);
      return Observable.of(true);
    } else {

      if (sessionStorage.getItem('refresh_token') === null) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/sessiontimeout');
        this.authUserService.requireLoginSubject.next(true);
        return Observable.of(false);
      }

      this.oAuthService.refreshToken().then(() => 
      {
        console.log("refreshed token");
        this.authUserService.requireLoginSubject.next(false);
        return Observable.of(true);
      }).catch(() => {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/sessiontimeout');
        this.authUserService.requireLoginSubject.next(true);
        return Observable.of(false);
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: `canActivate` also supports promises. So instead you could choose to return `Promise.resolve(true)`. If you do have an observable somewhere, you can convert it to promise easily. `myObservable.toPromise()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forgot to add the return on the refresh case:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean>
{
    this.authUserService.lastUrl = state.url;

    if (this.oAuthService.hasValidAccessToken()) {
      this.authUserService.requireLoginSubject.next(false);
      return Observable.of(true);
    } else {

      if (sessionStorage.getItem('refresh_token') === null) {
        this.router.navigate(['/sessiontimeout']);
        this.authUserService.requireLoginSubject.next(true);
        return Observable.of(false);
      }

      return Observable.fromPromise(this.oAuthService.refreshToken())
             .mergeMap(()=>{
                       this.authUserService.requireLoginSubject.next(false);
                       return Observable.of(true);
              })
             .catch(()=>{
                      this.router.navigateByUrl('/sessiontimeout');
                      this.authUserService.requireLoginSubject.next(true);
                      return Observable.of(false);
              });
}
```

EDIT: Transformed the promise into an Observable for easier concatenation of operators.

Comment: `refreshToken()` is a promise.  I can't return it from here without transpile errors.

Comment: Yup, my bad. Im not really an expert with promises. I will edit my answer, but could you provide some more code? The guard class and the refreshToken method would be helpful

Comment: Does the refreshToken method returns a promise with no val?